# Invalid Digital Receipt Delivery URL in MIGS integration

Tags: php, payment-methods

Getting Error on the integration of MIGSusing PHP

Please Help

Getting Error
`Invalid Digital Receipt Delivery URL`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying from none https URL based.

So if you try from localhost install selfsigned SSL.
and if this is your website, then install SSL and it will work